# Trying to store Perl s// output in Bash

Tags: bash, perl

I've tried a million variations, but basically I want to be able to store the result of a complicated filename substitution.

```
newName=$(perl -e 's/(\d)to\d000(\d)/(5-$1)*10000+(7-$2)/e' <<< "$img")
```

Unfortunately, this stores nothing at all.  However, when I set Perl to print, like this:

```
perl -pe 's/(\d)to\d000(\d)/(5-$1)*10000+(7-$2)/e' <<< "$img"
```

I get the correct result printed.  Can someone help me store the returned value in a variable in bash?

Comment: Whats in `$img`? And why have you ommitted the `-p` from the first one?

Comment: a filename that looks like "turn0to10001.png"

Comment: Tried having perl print the output when putting it into a bash variable?  All bash does is capture stdout...

Comment: cool, add -p to your first example and you should be fine.

Comment: I thought it made no difference, but it turns out I was echoing the output incorrectly.  Wow!  Thanks.  Adding the -p back in really works. :)

Comment: @bobbylox: What is your expected output? Are you looking for other possible ways to achieve this?

Comment: @Inian : The op may not look for a better solution as what he has is already the best for what he intends to do. The `$1` is similar to `\1` in sed and look at these input/output samples to figure out the rest. `img="live6to50009"` -> `newName=live-10002` and `img="live4to50006"` gives `newName=live10001`

Comment: @sjsam: Yeah, figured out his expected output, thought with the `bash` tagged, may be can provide a `regEx` for the same.

Comment: @Inian : imho, you can't do arithmetic regex calculations with `bash`. You need a tool like perl for that. The reason why `bash` wass tagged may be because he is incorporating `perl` script inside a bash wrapper

Answer (score 2):

The assignment just captures the output (to `stdout`) of the `perl` command, so you need to have `perl` print the modified string after doing the substitution:

```
$ newName=$(perl -pe 's/(\d)to\d000(\d)/(5-$1)*10000+(7-$2)/e' <<< "turn0to10001.png")
$ echo $newName
turn50006.png
```